# DQL how to use max function with subquery

Tags: orm, doctrine-orm, dql

I have two tables called geocaching an geocaching_countries and now i want to build DQL query that is equivalent to this query in SQL:

```
SELECT g.id,g.name,g.long,g.lat,g.altitude,g.town, g.region, 
       g.district, g.geocaching_countries_id, gc.image FROM geocaching g 
       JOIN geocaching_countries gc ON geocaching_countries_id=gc.id 
       WHERE g.long=(SELECT max(geocaching.long) FROM geocaching);
```

I am beginner in ORM so I need your help with that.
Thanks